# How to create and Open a dialogue Box Dynamically on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I am trying to create and open a dialogue box dynamically and automatically on page load in jquery mobile page but not able to do it ..I think i am missing some thing but not able to get what ..
Here is my jquery code and function that is called on pageload..

```
function onLoad() { 

openDialogBox1(); 

document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
$("#searchby_chooser_ok_button").bind ("click", searchByCriteria); 

if (typeof Contact === "undefined") {
    getElement("contacts_list").innerHTML = "<p>The Cordova Contacts API is inaccessible</p>";
}
}

function openDialogBox1(){ 
$("#simplestring").simpledialog({
'mode' : 'string',
'prompt' : 'Please Enter Your Mobile No.',
'buttons' : {
'OK': {
   click: function () {
     $('#dialogoutput').text($('#dialoglink').attr('data-string'));
   }
 },
 'Cancel': {
   click: function () { },
   icon: "delete",
   theme: "c"
  }
 }
 })
 }
```

Please help me to correct my mistake ..Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

try changing this line:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
```

by this:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", openDialogBox1, false);
```

Comment: Do i need to change something in `openDialogBox1()` function also ?

Comment: it looks OK. Delete the first call to this function in the load. Did you put the simpledialog javascript lib?

Comment: NO i have not ..Can you please show me on Fiddle .Thanks

Comment: http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-SimpleDialog/demos/install.html the last line + css line

Comment: I will check and will let you know..Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using jquery you can try this:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

    openDialogBox1(); 

    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    $("#searchby_chooser_ok_button").bind ("click", searchByCriteria); 

    if (typeof Contact === "undefined") {
        getElement("contacts_list").innerHTML = "<p>The Cordova Contacts API is inaccessible</p>";
    }
    }

    function openDialogBox1(){ 
    $("#simplestring").simpledialog({
    'mode' : 'string',
    'prompt' : 'Please Enter Your Mobile No.',
    'buttons' : {
    'OK': {
       click: function () {
         $('#dialogoutput').text($('#dialoglink').attr('data-string'));
       }
     },
     'Cancel': {
       click: function () { },
       icon: "delete",
       theme: "c"
      }
     }
     })
   });
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer .Actually One point i wanted to share that This code is meant for Cordova Mobile App.and In my HTML Body I have called `OnLoad()` function like this .So i dont think it will work in that